# How to manage the application icon on the taskbar?

Tags: winapi, taskbar

Intro:
OS: Windows 10
DPI: 96

I got metrics of recommended sizes small (16x16) and large (32x32) icons of my application, called SetClassLong function to set him. Everything is working! 
BUT!! After launching the application, the icon displayed in the taskbar has a size of 24x24.
Why such a size? I setted only the recommended 16x16 and 32x32? How can I control the real icon in the taskbar (except for calling SetOverlayIcon)

Comment: You don't get to decide how jig the task bar is. The user decides that. Your job is to provide an icon that looks good at whatever size you find the task bar to be.

Comment: How can I give the system a 24x24 icon (which one should it be for other dpi?) If the metric request recommends me 16x16 and 32x32?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I give the system a 24x24 icon (which one should it be for
>   other dpi?) If the metric request recommends me 16x16 and 32x32?

Forget about the `GetSystemMetrics()` since it hasn't been updated in ages. To provide a 24x24 icon that Windows 10 uses for display on the task bar just set the `hIcon` member of your `WNDCLASS` to such icon.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll try, and what size icons should be for the other DPI?